# How to find repeating numbers in a string and display them in vb?

Tags: vb6

How can I find repeating integers from the input string and then find the sum of those repeating integers?

So far I have tried to find only integers from the string:

```
Function findInt(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim retStr As String
    Dim i As Integer
    retStr = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retStr = retStr + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    findInt = retStr
End Function
```

Sorry, im new here and also in programming :) Dont know how things work here yet :)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask]

Comment: So far I have tried to find only integers from the string.

 Function findInt(ByVal s As String) As String
        
        Dim retStr As String        
        Dim i As Integer
        retStr = ""

        For i = 1 To Len(s)
            If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
                retStr = retStr + Mid(s, i, 1)
            End If
        Next

        findInt = retStr
    End Function

Sorry, im new here and also in programming :) Dont know how things work here yet :)

Comment: can you show a sample of the string?

Comment: Its just a random string of integers entered by the user. For example something like this: 2344657789 @SuncoastOwner

Comment: Make sure to add code by **editing** your original question.

Comment: for string 2344657789 what is the outcome you want to achieve ?

Comment: the outcome would be 44 77

Answer (score 0):

loop through the string and test if the next character is the same as the current character.

```
'1 form with:
'  1 textbox control: name=Text1
'  1 command button : name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Caption = FindDoubles(Text1.Text)
End Sub

Private Function FindDoubles(strText As String) As String
  Dim lngIndex As Long
  Dim strFind As String
  Dim strDoubles As String
  strDoubles = ""
  For lngIndex = 1 To Len(strText) - 1
    strFind = Mid$(strText, lngIndex, 1)
    If Mid$(strText, lngIndex + 1, 1) = strFind Then
      strDoubles = strDoubles & strFind & strFind & " "
    End If
  Next lngIndex
  FindDoubles = strDoubles
End Function
```